# Is it better to subscribe to changes or a full data set?

Tags: design-patterns, service, microservices, publish-subscribe

Let's say that I have two services `A` and `B`. Service `A` has a set of items like `[ "foo", "bar" ]` and is the service responsible for bringing the items into the system. Service `B` needs to subscribe to this data set. There are 2 ways it could do that:

1. Subscribe to the full data set
2. Subscribe to the changes

To give a concrete example, let's say the data set goes through evolutions like

- `[ "foo", "bar" ]`
- `[ "foo", "bar", "baz" ]`
- `[ "foo",        "baz" ]`
- `[ "foo",        "baz", "buz" ]`

The messages sent to service `B` with each change could be exactly what's above or it could be like

- `{ add: [ "foo", "bar" ], subtract: [] }`
- `{ add: [ "baz" ], subtract: [] }`
- `{ add: [], subtract: [ "bar" ] }`
- `{ add: [ "buz" ], subtract: [] }`

The question is which would be better. My view is that the first is better for the following reasons

- **Eventual consistency.** In the first, if a message gets lost or there's some other failure so that `B` doesn't process a message, it will always be corrected when it successfully processes another message. In the second, there would be a lot of complexity to be added to the system to automatically correct these fail scenarios.
- **Idemptoency.** Similar to the above point, if service `A` sends duplicate messages by accident, that's totally fine in the first design, whereas as the second design that case would require extra complexity to treat.
- **Delta is not really an optimization.** Initially it sounds like an optimization to say "The rest of our system will only process the changes," but the thing is that *someone* has to compute the changes, so why should `A` rather than `B`, and how does this reduce the total number of operations?

Answer (score 0):

So you pointed out the benefits for subscribing to whole dataset rather than just the delta, and each of these points are well considered and in most cases it is not worth it to put an effort to mange the deltas, from subscribers perspective.

But I would like you to look from the producers perspective. Producer must be working on certain events, say add and sub. When events get generated, all it has is "Baz".
He will process the operation and then query his system to check whole data and send it out.
However he could have just send you out

> { add: [ "baz" ], subtract: [] }

So in cases like these it will be less expensive for the producer to send you delta.
Another thing to note is how many time these queries are happening and why you subscriber need this. If you take a case of say inventory in shop then any buy event will remove inventory and any return may add.
There will be way too many events like these, and if we send out inventory update everytime there is a buy event by actually reading from the system, that might be lil slow.

Other side of this story, why subscriber need this, he may need it to see if he can display the product. If thats the case he not be really concerned if inventory 10 or 11 or 9.
He is worried about if its nearing zero or not, in that case delta updates might make sense.

But delta updates alone may not help you. Like you said they are not idempotent nor consistent. And to fix that out, I prefer making use of both.

Send delta updates in smaller intervals. Let the system go bad, but correct it before it goes too bad by pushing complete datasets.

For those who can live with the shortcomings of delta can consume less reliable but fast delta updates and for those who looking for consistency make use of full data updates. You however restrict them based on producers limitation. If they are costly, you do it less frequently.

So is one better over the other?
I will say, it depends on your use case, you can prefer one over the other or they can both be used to complement each other.

Answer (score 0):

First notice that if you're working with a *set*, operations like "add" and "subtract" are idempotent, as long as you don't change the order (it's actually a useful property at least in some cases, since in some scenarios your "server" can send second message with the same action without messing client data).

Second, as one working with a diff-based system for the last year, I *strongly* advise to avoid this if sending full datasets is feasible. When you start editing the same data by several entities, things get complicated fast.

Third, diff-based approach is better when the size of whole data is much larger than the size of updated data (say, 10^6 items while you're changing two or three at a time). When displaying data you usually need a delta (so that, say, in UI you remove two rows from a list rather than erasing the whole list and then creating it again); calculating it from two large blocks of data may take time. Also, trying to operate on whole datasets also becomes problematic when they don't fit in memory anymore (and resending clients mega- or even gigabytes of data at every action is less than wise).